# ExpoKit: No known instance method for selector 'moduleRegistry'

Tags: objective-c, react-native, expo

I'm currently trying to update the expo SDK from 35 -> 37, as of yet this has proven to be a real nightmare. Currently I've been facing this error with XCode 12.5 in the deprecated Expokit `No known instance method for selector 'moduleRegistry'`

The error is inside **EXAppState.m**, under the TODO (which is not mine). I don't even know where the error comes from, so any guidance would be perfect.

```
- (void)setState:(NSString *)state
{
  if (![state isEqualToString:_lastKnownState]) {
    _lastKnownState = state;
    if (_isObserving) {
      [self sendEventWithName:@"appStateDidChange"
                         body:@{@"app_state": _lastKnownState}];
    }
   
    // change state on universal modules
    // TODO: just make EXAppState a universal module implementing UMAppLifecycleService
    id<UMAppLifecycleService> lifeCycleManager = [[[self.bridge moduleForClass:[UMModuleRegistryHolderReactModule class]] moduleRegistry] getModuleImplementingProtocol:@protocol(UMAppLifecycleService)];
    if ([state isEqualToString:@"background"]) {
      [lifeCycleManager setAppStateToBackground];
    } else if ([state isEqualToString:@"active"]) {
      [lifeCycleManager setAppStateToForeground];
    }
  }
}
```

I know that I should be using Bare workflow instead, but currently my company doesn't allow me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone who reached this point, give up. It's easier to upgrade your app to bare. Personally, I've spent 3 whole weeks to solve problems like this one after another and there was no end.